# Unet. Multiplayer Vehicles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I am currently developing multiplayer fps shooter, and i am stuck on vehicles.

i tried these "ClientRpc" stuff, "Command" and etc. So Player has Controll script, and this script has function OnControllerColliderHit, so if this happens i call void Disable();

in this method, i disable all colliders and some components i don't need like: shooting, moving, camera etc...

> basically all i need is: Disable some player components when he gets
>   in car. script works perfectly in singleplayer, but in multiplayer it
>   looks really weird.

*I have also asked this on Unity answers, but didn't get any:* http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1235436/ *(scripts are there)*

ps(if you'll need some more info or scripts for me to post, just comment. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are only enabling/disabling components in the server. Commands are called on the server only, so you might want to use [RPC](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.ClientRpcAttribute.html) to do the same in the clients.

```
 void Update()
 {
     //if there is driver in car then we can controll it. (it's a paradox for me, if there is driver and i am passanger i also can controll it lol.)
     if(hasDriver)
     {
         GetComponent<carController>().enabled = true;
     }
     else
     {
         GetComponent<carController>().enabled = false;
     }
 }

 //command function for sitting. in car.
 [Command]
 public void CmdSit(string _player)
 {
     //i increase how many people are in car
     sitPlayers++;

     cam.enabled = true;
     //find player who sat there.
     GameObject player = GameObject.Find(_player);



     //i think you will get it >>
     if (hasDriver)
     {
         player.transform.parent = Sitter.transform;
         player.transform.position = Sitter.transform.position;
         cam.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = true;


     }
     else
     {
         player.transform.parent = Driver.transform;
         hasDriver = true;
         cam.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = true;
         player.transform.position = Driver.transform.position;             
     }

     RpcSit(_player, hasDriver);

 }

[ClientRpc]
public void RpcSit(string _player, bool _driver)
{
     cam.enabled = true;
     //find player who sat there.
     GameObject player = GameObject.Find(_player);

     //i think you will get it >>
     if (_driver)
     {
         player.transform.parent = Sitter.transform;
         player.transform.position = Sitter.transform.position;
         cam.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = true;
     }
     else
     {
         player.transform.parent = Driver.transform;
         cam.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = true;
         player.transform.position = Driver.transform.position;
     }
}
```